# AJAX/PHP isnt working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So i want to submit some data (from a form) into the server-database using AJAX but for some reason it seams that the AJAX script isnt working at all. When i submit the form the PHP script executes with no problem though. I looked all over the place for an answer but nothing worked so far. It might be something stupid but i need some help anyways.

Jquery/AJAX script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#InputForm').submit(function(){

     var that = $(this),
         url = that.attr('action'),
         type = that.attr('method'),
         data = {};


     that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value){
         var that = $(this),
             name = that.attr('name'),
             value = that.val();

         data[name] = value;    
     });

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        async: true,
        type: type,
        data: data,
        success: function(response){
            $(#Suc_Sub).fadeIn(800);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

});

PHP and HTML script:

```
$url = "";
$email = "";
$comment = "";
$stage = "";

$url_error = "";
$email_error = "";
$comment_error = "";



if(!empty($_POST['websiteURL']))
{
    $url = $_POST['websiteURL'];
    $regex = "/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i";
    if (!preg_match( $regex, $url) )
    {
        $url_error = "Invalid Url";
    }
}
else
{
    $url_error = "Url is blank";
}



if(!empty($_POST['userEmail']))
{           
    $email = $_POST['userEmail'];
    $email = fix_input($email);
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) 
    {
        $email_error = "Invalid email";
    }
}
else
{
    $email_error = "Email is blank";
}


if(!empty($_POST['userComment']))
{
    $comment = $_POST['userComment'];
    $comment = fix_input($comment);
    $regex = "/^[A-Za-z0-9 _]*[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9 _]*$/";
    if (!preg_match( $regex, $comment) )
    {
        $comment_error = "Invalid Comment";
    }
}
else
{
    $comment_error = "Comment is blank";
}


$stage = $_POST['websiteStage'];


if(empty($email_error) && empty($url_error) && empty($comment_error))
{
    $date_parts = getdate(date("U"));
    $post_date = "$date_parts[mday]-$date_parts[mon]-$date_parts[year] - $date_parts[hours]:$date_parts[minutes]:$date_parts[seconds]";
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO submit (URL,EMAIL,COMMENT,STAGE,Date) 
    VALUES ('$url','$email','$comment','$stage','$post_date')");
    die();
}
else
{
    die();
}


<form method="post" id="InputForm" action="..\Scripts\sbt.php"> 
            <fieldset style="border:none">
                <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
                    <li>
                        <label for="websiteURL"> <img src="..\Images\blank tick.png" id="Website_Image" height="50" width="60"> </label> <!--Dont forget about the label pics-->
                        <input size="25" autocomplete="off" title="Type your URL" type="url" id="websiteURL_Box" class="TextInput" name="websiteURL" required="required" placeholder="Your Website URL..." autofocus="autofocus" maxlength="100"/>
                        <div id="flyout_hidden_url" hidden></div>
                    </li><br>

                    <li>
                        <label for="userEmail"> <img src="..\Images\blank tick.png" id="Email_Image" height="50" width="60"> </label> <!--Dont forget about the label pics-->
                        <input size="25" autocomplete="off" title="Your Email plz" type="email" id="userEmail_Box" class="TextInput" name="userEmail" required="required"required="required" placeholder="Your Email..." autofocus="autofocus" maxlength="100"/>
                        <div id="flyout_hidden_email" hidden></div>
                    </li><br>

                    <li>
                        <label for="userComment"> <img src="..\Images\blank tick.png" id="Comment_Image" height="50" width="60"> </label> <!--Dont forget about the label pics-->
                        <input size="25" autocomplete="off" title="Your Comment" type="text" id="userComment_Box" class="TextInput" name="userComment" placeholder="Any comments...?" autofocus="autofocus" maxlength="100"/>
                        <div id="flyout_hidden_comment" hidden></div>
                    </li><br>

                    <li>
                        <label for="websiteStage"> </label> 
                        <select name="websiteStage" class="custom">
                            <option value="Alpha">Alpha Version</option>
                            <option value="Beta">Beta Version</option>
                            <option value="Finished">Finished</option>
                        </select>
                    </li><br>

                    <li>
                        <label id="botTest_Label" for="botQuestion">I am not a cyborg!</label> <!--Dont forget about the label pics-->
                        <input type="checkbox"  required="required" value="botQ" id="botTest_Box" title="For Bot testing!">
                    </li><br>
                    <input id="SubmitButton" type="submit" disabled value="Submit">
                </ul>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What "doesn't work"? Any error messages? You are open to SQL injections, use prepared statements..

Comment: We can't debug this for you.  When you debug it, where specifically does it fail?  As you step through the JavaScript code, does it do what you expect?  Is the POST request made?  Does it contain the data you expect?  What is the server's response?

Comment: When i submit the form it just executes the PHP script. And when i check console log to see if anything is wrong it doesnt say anything. Its like it doesnt exist.

Comment: enable error reporting in the php file: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: have you tried running fiddler and looking at your traffic? Thats the first thing I would do. See if your client is sending the right request

Comment: What doesn't work? You're aware that you're not returning anything to the ajax call, and that you're missing quotes around the selector for the fadein ?

Comment: Please provide the form-code (html). Does the form submit with method 'POST'?

Comment: Yes the form is with POST.

Comment: and it would help to replace the `success` param by the `done` _and_ `fail` delegated events. Putting an `alert` in the `fail` method may help understand what is happening.

Comment: Is your `action` pointing to the correct page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please alter the ajax-call into the following:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: type,
    data: data
}).done(function(){
    $('#Suc_Sub').fadeIn(800);
}).fail(function(){
    alert('fail!');
});
```

Important:

- Use quotes around `'#Suc_Sub'` (as commented by @adeneo). I presume that there is actually some element with this id?

Other notes:

- The `async` paremeter is `true` by default.
- The `type` parameter is an old alias for `method`.
- Using the delegated functions help to better understand what's happening. If the response has a status other than `200 OK` (for example a `404 Not Found` because the script was not found), you will still see that the event fired.

Comment: Well now for some reason the PHP script is executed twice. The AJAX works and the fadeIn works too. But after the animation it executes the PHP script too so i get twice the submission in my database. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the `return false;` statement after the ajax-call still there? (perhaps put `console.log('returning false');` _just_ before `return false;` for debugging). Note that this will propable occur even before the ajax call returns, because it is asynchronous.

Comment: That might also be caused by something in your code that was not in your initial question. I do not currently see anything wrong with it...

Comment: Let me check if there is anything else that might cause the problem.

Comment: Nah i cant find anything that would make the script execute twice. sadly :'(

Comment: Its ok thank you very much for your help, i finally found the problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is incorrect in your jQuery:

```
$(#Suc_Sub).fadeIn(800);
```

should be

```
$('#Suc_Sub').fadeIn(800);
```

OR

```
$("#Suc_Sub").fadeIn(800);
```

If this is not the issue. I would begin to put out some specfic values in the console.log and look in the console if the values are expected to use within the ajax-call.

```
console.log('url =' + url);
console.log('type = ' + type);
console.log(data);

$.ajax({
        url: url,
        async: true,
        type: type,
        data: data,
        success: function(response){
            $(#Suc_Sub).fadeIn(800);
        }
    });
```

If everything seems "normal" I would rewrite your code as this:

```
var formvalues = $.ajax({
   url: url,
   async: true,
   type: type,
   data: data,
});

formvalues.done(function(data) {  
        console.log('success =' + data);
});                        

formvalues.fail(function(ts) {           
    alert(ts.responseText);
   });
```

If the ajax-call fails you would get an alert and then you would also get a clue what your issue is about.